# datepicker show full day names instead of short names

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to show full week day names, instead of the short ones? When showing the calendar.

I mean instead of:

`Su Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa`,

Show these:

`Sunday  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Santurday`

Answer (score 4):

To improve on the answer, instead of rewriting the days labels you can use the datepicker defaults options, which will preserve the defined locale:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: $.datepicker._defaults.dayNames, //or dayNamesShort
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me in year 2022.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the [dayNamesMin](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dayNamesMin) option:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
});
```

and add the CSS to account for the change in width to the calendar:

```
.ui-datepicker {
    width:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gjt7otac/)**